# Pass URL containing a query string as a parameter ASP.Net Web API GET?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, url-parameters, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm trying to pass in an URL as a string parameter to a WEB API GET method.

The controller:

```
public class LinksController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(string targetUrl)
    {
        //query db with targetURL
    }
}
```

The aim is to query the database to see if the URL is stored. This works fine with simple URLs and URLs whose query string contains a single parameter, like:

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLPE4vhSBx4

The problem I'm encountering is specifically when the query string contains multiple parameters, e.g.

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLPE4vhSBx4&feature=youtube_gdata

When debugging, the value of targetUrl is only ".../watch?v=nLPE4vhSBx4" which means **&feature=youtube_gdata is lost**.

The GET request looks like this:

```
http://localhost:58056/api/links?targetUrl=http://www.youtube.com/watch? v=nLPE4vhSBx4&feature=youtube_gdata
```

I've also tried to add the following route in WebApiConfig.cs:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Links",
    routeTemplate: "api/links/{targetUrl}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Links", targetUrl= RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

But the GET request then results in 400 Bad Request.

So my question is, can't this be done? I would like the complete URL! Or would I need to change the method header to use the `[FromBody]` attribute and pass it as a JSON object?

Answer (score 1):

You should `URLEncode` your target URL parameter so that it doesn't get mistaken for subsequent query string parameter. This means the URL you specified should appear as:

```
http://localhost:58056/api/links?targetUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DnLPE4vhSBx4%26feature%3Dyoutube_gdata
```

And then inside your Get method, `URLDecode` the string that is passed as a parameter.

Both methods can be found in [`System.Web.HttpUtility`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.HttpUtility_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)